# proper way to pattern match with escaped char

Tags: java, pattern-matching

Pattern.matches("123$45","123$45") returns false, I presume because of the special $ char.

My suspicion was that escaping the $ would make it pass

e.g. Pattern.matches("123\$45","123\$45")

But this also fails.

What is the proper way to make sure they match?

Comment: This is one of the brain-bugs or design flaws — or more charitably, unfortunate consequences — of Java’s unintegrated regex library: you don’t actually get to use actual regex syntax because of having to double-escape the escape character (backslash). This could have been easily solved, but they weren’t creative enough. So everyone in Java is stuck with a very confusing situation, one that almost all other tools and languages have devised some far more tolerable solution to.

Comment: @tchrist - have you tried regexes in C / C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pattern you are looking for is fixed pattern, then manually escape the `'$'` character so that it isn't treated as a regex metacharacter; i.e.

```
 boolean itMatches = Pattern.matches("123\\$45", "123$45");
```

The `'$'` is escaped at the level of the String object using a single backslash.  However, since we are expressing this using a String *literal*, and backslash is the escape character for string literals, we need to (string) escape the (regex) escape character.  Hence, we need two backslashes ... here.

If you don't escape the escape, the Java compiler says in effect "I don't recognize "\$" as a valid String literal escape sequence.  ERROR!".

---

On the other hand, if the pattern input or generated, then you can use `Pattern.quote()` to quote it; i.e.

```
 String literal = "123$45";  // ... or any literal string you want to match.

 boolean itMatches = Pattern.matches(Pattern.quote(literal), "123$45");
```

Comment: All the answers listed so far have been great, and are helpful.  But adding Pattern.quote is the one that really solved it for me.

Answer (score 7):

This is the "canonical" regex which is `\$`, but here this is a Java string. And in a Java string, a `\` is written `"\\"`. Therefore:

```
"123\\$45"
```

As to your target string, it just needs to be `"123$45"`.